# POST request with wrk?

Tags: benchmarking, wrk

I started to try [wrk](https://github.com/wg/wrk). It's very simple to use and very hard on the server, but I don't know how to perform other kind of request such as POST. In fact, I don't even know if this tool allows it. The documentation is very minimal.

Thanks

Answer (score 87, accepted):

This is possible now. Here is an example https://github.com/wg/wrk/blob/master/scripts/post.lua.

```
wrk.method = "POST"
wrk.body   = "foo=bar&baz=quux"
wrk.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

save this in a `*.lua` script and pass it into your command line test with the `-s` flag.

Comment: wow! Let me check that out. I'll switch the answer to your's if I can manage to make it work. Thanks for coming back to that post.

Comment: You sir, are a life saver ! Just what I wanted. A simple and elegant way to test my post APIs. +1

Answer (score 40):

for those looking for a content-type "application/json" example:

```
wrk.method = "POST"
wrk.body = '{"firstKey": "somedata", "secondKey": "somedata"}'
wrk.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
```

Comment: To post json data, this formatting actually works for me:
`wrk.body = '{"firstKey": "somedata", "secondKey": "somedata"}'`

Answer (score 14):

Here's an example lua script `post_binary.lua` for posting binary file: `"Content-Type:application/octet-stream"`.

```
wrk.method = "POST"
wrk.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/octet-stream"

file = io.open("dog.jpg", "rb")
wrk.body = file:read("*a")
```

Then try: `wrk "your_url" -s post_binary.lua --latency -t 1 -c 1 -d 30s -R 1`

Comment: Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 12):

I'll recommend using `wrk2` instead of `wrk` since wrk2 provides better support for concurrent requests.  When `content-type` header is `application/json` then please escape the special characters like `\n` with `\\n` and all other special characters present. Not doing this will send an invalid json to the upstream API, which will waste your time debugging.

Create a file with extension `lua` and paste the following in it. Save it and pass it along with `-s` flag to wrk2 command.

```
wrk.method = "POST"
wrk.body = "{\"firstKey\": 'somedata', \"secondKey\": 'somedata'}"
wrk.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
```

Also you can add multiple header as

```
wrk.headers["Header1"] = "Header1_Val"
wrk.headers["Header2"] = "Header2_Val"
wrk.headers["Header3"] = "Header3_Val"
wrk.headers["Header4"] = "Header4_Val"
```

```
wrk2 -t500 -c1000 -d160s -R10000 -s ~/Documents/luaTestScript.lua http://localhost:8080/test_endpoint
```